# solr faceted search UI development

Tags: solr

I am working on a POC, where I have to display faceted search result on web page. can anybody please help me to suggest what all set up I need to configure to display. I would prefer java technologies. Just to mention, I have solr cloud running on remote server.
I would like to know:
1. Should I use MVC framework?
2. How will my local interact with remote solr server?
3. How will I send query through java code and what technology I should use to display faceted search result?

or any example how someone is doing will be very helpful.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

One of the quickest ways to create your POC is by using the [VelocityResponseWriter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter), this response writter is bundled in Solr distribution, it's basically a series of Apache Velocity templates that are very easy to customize.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, As I mentioned solr cloud configuration is running in remote server, will I be able to work on my local VelocityResponseWriter to query remote server and customize templates in my local. If so, what all I should have in my local to run this setup?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can use the VelocityResponseWritter templates in your local environment to display search results on remote search, unfortunately there's no detailed documentation about how to use these templates out of box, you must read the wiki page to get an idea about how to do it.